# Xcode app on iPhone6+ can't open file for binary read

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to open a file 'd.mp3' that I added to my Xcode 8.0 project.
If I double-click Xcode > project > 'd.mp3' the file plays just fine.
But, when Xcode runs my app on my iPhone6+ (iOS 10.0.1) then fopen() returns 0 for the file handle.

Code and output below...

```
bool read_next_chunk( char* relative_file_pathname, unsigned char* chunk_buffer, int chunk_size_bytes, FILE* file_handle  )
```

{
    const bool dbg = true;

```
// Get absolute file pathname:
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *program_directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* absolute_pathname = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/%s", program_directory, relative_file_pathname ];

if( dbg )   printf("\n%s:  file '%s'.  Path '%s'.", __FUNCTION__, relative_file_pathname, [absolute_pathname UTF8String] );

// Open file if not already open:
if( file_handle == NULL )
{
    if( dbg ) printf("\n%s    Open file %s.", __FUNCTION__, relative_file_pathname );
    file_handle = fopen( [absolute_pathname UTF8String], "rb" );         // open for binary reading
    if( dbg ) printf("\n%s    file_handle %d.", __FUNCTION__, file_handle);
}
if( file_handle )
{
    // Read next chunk of file into file_content_string:
    int total_read_bytes = (int)fread( chunk_buffer, 1, chunk_size_bytes, file_handle );
    if( total_read_bytes != chunk_size_bytes )
    {
        printf("\n %s:   %d total_read_bytes != %d chunk_size_bytes -- FAULT!!  <<<<<<<<<<<",__FUNCTION__, total_read_bytes, chunk_size_bytes);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
else
{
    printf("\ %s:   Cannot open '%s' FAULT!!  <<<<<<<<<<<", __FUNCTION__, relative_file_pathname );
    return false;
}
```

}

read_next_chunk:  file 'd.mp3'.    Path '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C8B87C49-C6CF-4677-B775-6B3DF6EFD908/Documents/d.mp3'.
read_next_chunk       Open file d.mp3.
read_next_chunk       file_handle 0. read_next_chunk:   Cannot open 'd.mp3' FAULT!!  <<<<<<<<<<<

Comment: If the file is bundled in your app, it won't be in the Documents folder. Access it using `NSBundle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As rmaddy said, it is likely not in your documents directory. Try something like this:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"d" ofType:@"mp3"];
```